# Get Values from JSON Array using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the below json array returned from web api and I need to get some values from it.
For example how do I get all the rides in first place and how do I get rides[1]. UserID or Images?

```
   {
   "Status":1,
   "Rides":[
         {
         "RideID":abc,
         "UserID":111,
         "RideName":"123 ",
         "RideStatus":1,
         "Description":"Join for a fun filled weekend ride,
         "Images":[
            "https://xxxcom/123.png"
         ],
         "StartDate":"2020-09-06",
         "StartTime":"6:30:00",
         "EndDate":"2020-09-06",
         "EndTime":"11:00:00",
         "StartLocationName":"Delhi",
         "StartLocationLat":123.456,
         "StartLocationLong":90.2345,
         "DestinationLocationName":"India",
        },
        {
         "RideID":def,
         "UserID":222,
         "RideName":"345",
         "RideStatus":1,
         "Description":"Join for a fun filled weekend ride,
         "Images":[
            "https://xxxcom/456.png"
         ],
         "StartDate":"2020-09-06",
         "StartTime":"6:30:00",
         "EndDate":"2020-09-06",
         "EndTime":"11:00:00",
         "StartLocationName":"Bombay"
         "DestinationLocationName":"India",
        },
        ]

 }
```

Comment: It depends upon how your are getting the data.  If it is a JSON string, you'll need to parse it first with data = JSON.parse(data).  If you retrieved it via fetch or jQuery as json it would already be JSON.  Then the Rides array would just be data.Rides.

Answer (score 0):

Was that the point?

```
const response = '{"Status":1,"Rides":[{"RideID":"abc","UserID":111,"RideName":"123 ","RideStatus":1,"Description":"Join for a fun filled weekend ride","Images":["https://xxxcom/123.png"],"StartDate":"2020-09-06","StartTime":"6:30:00","EndDate":"2020-09-06","EndTime":"11:00:00","StartLocationName":"Delhi","StartLocationLat":123.456,"StartLocationLong":90.2345,"DestinationLocationName":"India"},{"RideID":"def","UserID":222,"RideName":"345","RideStatus":1,"Description":"Join for a fun filled weekend ride","Images":["https://xxxcom/456.png"],"StartDate":"2020-09-06","StartTime":"6:30:00","EndDate":"2020-09-06","EndTime":"11:00:00","StartLocationName":"Bombay","DestinationLocationName":"India"}]}';
const json = JSON.parse(response);
const rides = json.Rides || [];

rides.forEach(function (ride) {
  const rideId = ride.RideID || null;
  const userId = ride.UserID || null;
  const images = ride.Images || [];
  
  console.log(rideId, userId, images.join(','));
});
```

You can check the above code here: https://jsfiddle.net/wjqvfLxr/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).